# Quick way to get the difference between two List<> objects

Tags: c#, list

How do I get `itemsToRemove` to only contain "bar one", and `itemsToAdd` to only contain "bar five"?

I'm trying to use "Except", but obviously I'm using it incorrectly.

```
var oldList = new List<Foo>();
oldList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar one"});
oldList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar two"});
oldList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar three"});
oldList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar four"});



var newList = new List<Foo>();
newList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar two"});
newList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar three"});
newList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar four"});
newList.Add(new Foo(){ Bar = "bar five"});


var itemsToRemove = oldList.Except(newList);    // should only contain "bar one"
var itemsToAdd = newList.Except(oldList);    // should only contain "bar one"


foreach(var item in itemsToRemove){
    Console.WriteLine(item.Bar + " removed");
    // currently says 
    // bar one removed
    // bar two removed
    // bar three removed
    // bar four removed
}


foreach(var item in itemsToAdd){
    Console.WriteLine(item.Bar + " added");
    // currently says 
    // bar two added
    // bar three added
    // bar four added
    // bar five added
}
```

Comment: I think you have to define Equals properly on your Foo class or to compare properties instead of class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Except` will use the default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method of the objects in question to define "equality" for the objects, unless you provide a custom comparer (you have not).  In this case, that will compare the references of the objects, not their `Bar` value.

One option would be to create an `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` that compares the `Bar` property, rather than references to the object itself.

```
public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        if (x == null ^ y == null)
            return false;
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;
        return x.Bar == y.Bar;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;
        return obj.Bar.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Another option is to create an `Except` method that accepts a selector to compare the values on.  We can create such a method and then use that:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    var set = new HashSet<TKey>(second.Select(keySelector), comparer);
    return first.Where(item => set.Add(keySelector(item)));
}
```

This allows us to write:

```
var itemsToRemove = oldList.ExceptBy(newList, foo => foo.Bar);
var itemsToAdd = newList.ExceptBy(oldList, foo => foo.Bar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is sound, but `Except` default behaviour for comparing two classes is to go by references. Since you are effectively create two lists with 8 differents objets (regardless of their content), there will be no two equal objects.

You can, however, use the [`Except` overload that takes an IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx). For example:

```
public class FooEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo> 
{
    public bool Equals(Foo left, Foo right) 
    {
        if(left == null && right == null) return true;

        return left != null && right != null && left.Bar == right.Bar;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo item)
    {
        return item != null ? item.Bar.GetHashcode() : 0;
    }
}

// In your code

var comparer = new FooEqualityComparer();
var itemsToRemove = oldList.Except(newList, comparer ); 
var itemsToAdd = newList.Except(oldList, comparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a riff on Servy's answer to give a more general approach to this:

```
public class PropertyEqualityComparer<TItem, TKey> : EqualityComparer<Tuple<TItem, TKey>>
{
    readonly Func<TItem, TKey> _getter;
    public PropertyEqualityComparer(Func<TItem, TKey> getter)
    {
        _getter = getter;
    }

    public Tuple<TItem, TKey> Wrap(TItem item) {
        return Tuple.Create(item, _getter(item));
    }

    public TItem Unwrap(Tuple<TItem, TKey> tuple) {
        return tuple.Item1;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Tuple<TItem, TKey> x, Tuple<TItem, TKey> y)
    {
        if (x.Item2 == null && y.Item2 == null) return true;
        if (x.Item2 == null || y.Item2 == null) return false;
        return x.Item2.Equals(y.Item2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Tuple<TItem, TKey> obj)
    {

        if (obj.Item2 == null) return 0;
        return obj.Item2.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public static class ComparerLinqExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, Func<TSource, TKey> keyGetter)
    {
        var comparer = new PropertyEqualityComparer<TSource, TKey>(keyGetter);
        var firstTuples = first.Select(comparer.Wrap);
        var secondTuples = second.Select(comparer.Wrap);
        return firstTuples.Except(secondTuples, comparer)
                          .Select(comparer.Unwrap);
    }
}
// ...
var itemsToRemove = oldList.Except(newList, foo => foo.Bar);
var itemsToAdd = newList.Except(oldList, foo => foo.Bar);
```

This should work fine for any classes without unusual equality semantics, where it's incorrect to call the `object.Equals()` override instead of `IEquatable<T>.Equals()`.Notably, this will work fine for anonymous types.

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue in this particular case, but it's important to be careful with this solution as it calls the property getter multiple times for each object.  That could cause problems if it's either computationally expensive to compute, or if it has side effects.  Your class also doesn't handle null values from the projected values, and will box any projected value types.  The second solution that I provided provides the same general functionality without any of these drawbacks.

Comment: It's also worth noting that anonymous types override their `Equals` methods to compare all of the underlying values, rather than using identity semantics.

Comment: I admit mine is a quick-and-dirty solution. It's really mostly intended to be used to grab one or more properties from an object and use those as the comparison key. The null-safety I'll agree is problematic. The property of anonymous types you mention is desirable here - the idea is to be able to express, say `people.Distinct(person=>new{person.FirstName, person.LastName});` succintly.

Comment: Your type should also implement `IEqualityComparer<TItem>` rather than extending `EqualityComparer<TItem>`.  I assume that's just a typo, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Servy That's intentional. It's what `EqualityComparer` is for. See the [Remarks on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx): "Derive from this class to provide a custom implementation of the IEqualityComparer<T> generic interface for use with collection classes such as the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> generic class, or with methods such as List<T>.Sort." I believe the idea is that `EqualityComparer<TItem>` overrides `Object.Equals` appropriately for you to redirect to the `IEqualityComparer<TItem>.Equals` method.

Comment: Yes, the base class implementation properly supports null values, but you don't use the base class's implementation, you override it, replacing it with one that *doesn't* properly null check.  Here's a simple example that demonstrates it:  `var comparer = new PropertyEqualityComparer<string>(s => null); Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(""));`  It throws.

Comment: @Servy Yeah I checked that and edited my code to use the same null checks as `EqualityComparer` does. The only thing that remains is the "expensive key" issue, which I guess is solvable using the decorate-undecorate pattern but that could clutter the code a bit too much. I'll try and see what I'll come up with, but it's something that can be done at the use site when necessary anyway.

Comment: Right, turns out decorate-undecorate isn't that much bother to add inside. (Although the code could use some cleanup now.)

Comment: @Servy Okay, this version should not really recompute the key (unless the `IEnumerable` is enumerated multiple times by the underlying LINQ method), and will always have the same semantics as said method. The only thing missing now is abstracting the decorate-do stuff with comparer-undecorate pattern into a helper method to avoid the boilerplate in overrides for `Except()`, `Distinct()`, etc, but that's likely nontrivial because the first takes two sequences, the latter only one.

Comment: Yes, your edit now prevents the multiple selector calls and also avoids the boxing (but creates a bunch of `Tuples`, which is pretty much just as bad), it just does it in a lot more code than in my answer ;) - As to dealing with the overloads, that's one of the advantages of the convention that this method be named `ExceptBy` rather than `Except`; it avoid the overload conflicts.

Comment: @Servy When I mentioned "overloads", what I was wondering was whether there's a way to create a higher-order function to abstract the decorate-call LINQ with the comparer-undecorate pattern to be make it possible to lift any LINQ function that takes a comparer into one that takes a `Func` as above. As for the tuples: premature optimisation etc. LINQ to begin with isn't exactly light on garbage objects anyway.

Comment: @Servy I'll agree your method is simpler for the OP's use case, but it does hinge on reimplementing the underlying LINQ method. My aim was to present a general pattern that would let you convert **any** method that takes an enumerable and a comparer into a method that takes an enumerable and a lambda, without having to reimplement said method. E.g. to make an analogous overload of `Enumerable.Distinct()`, you just need to copy-paste `Except()`, replace the name, and get rid of `second` and `secondWrapped`. (And, in the process got rid of some potential bugs in my original utility, thanks :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're comparing objects of type `Foo`, and not property Bar of type `string`. Try:

```
var itemsToRemove = oldList.Select(i => i.Bar).Except(newList.Select(i => i.Bar));
var itemsToAdd = newList.Select(i => i.Bar).Except(oldList.Select(i => i.Bar));
```

Comment: This leaves you with `Bar` objects in the end, not `Foo` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Implement IComparable on your data objects; I think you're being bitten by reference comparison. If you change Foo to just string, your code works.

```
        var oldList = new List<string>();
        oldList.Add("bar one");
        oldList.Add("bar two");
        oldList.Add("bar three");
        oldList.Add("bar four");

        var newList = new List<string>();
        newList.Add("bar two");
        newList.Add("bar three");
        newList.Add("bar four");
        newList.Add("bar five");

        var itemsToRemove = oldList.Except(newList);    // should only contain "bar one"
        var itemsToAdd = newList.Except(oldList);    // should only contain "bar one"

        foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item + " removed");
        }


        foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item + " added");
        }
```